# django python date time set to midnight

Tags: python, django, date, datetime, date-manipulation

I have a date time of my django object but it can be any time of the day. It can be at any time through the day, but I need to set my time to 00:00:00 (and another date to 23:59:59 but the principle will be the same)

```
end_date = lastItem.pub_date
```

currently the end date is 2002-01-11 12:34:56
What do I need to do to get this to change it to 00:00:00?

i tried:

```
end_date.hour = '00'
```

but got: 'datetime.datetime' object attribute 'time' is read-only

Comment: you need a datetime variable initialized to 00:00:00?

Comment: related: [How do I get the UTC time of “midnight” for a given timezone?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/373370/4279)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try this:

```
import datetime
pub = lastItem.pub_date
end_date = datetime.datetime(pub.year, pub.month, pub.day)
```

Comment: An alternative would be `end_date.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)`.

Comment: To ensure it's totally zeroed out, you may need to add microsecond=0 to F.J's suggestion. For instance, when you're zeroing out the time portion of datetime.now().

Comment: @F.J Are you sure? I get "'second' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" (or 'hour', or 'minute') when I do that. And it's a datetime object not a date. Maybe I was doing something wrong tho.

Comment: @RThiede [`datetime.datetime.replace()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) is working fine for me with `second` and `microsecond` keyword arguments, make sure that you have a `datetime.datetime` instance and not a `datetime.date`.

Comment: @AndrewClark: 1. you forgot `microsecond` in your first comment. 2. `.replace()` may return an unnormalized value for an aware datetime object that may introduce ~1h error around DST transitions. Both `.combine()` and `datetime()` methods strip the timezone info so that you can [add the correct value instead of using by accident a possibly incorrect value returned by `.replace()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11236372/4279)

Comment: @AndrewClark - this should be an individual answer, adding the microsecond part as said by anh

Answer (score 66):

Using datetimes's "combine" with the time.min and time.max will give both of your datetimes.
For example:

```
from datetime import date, datetime, time
pub_date = date.today()
min_pub_date_time = datetime.combine(pub_date, time.min) 
max_pub_date_time = datetime.combine(pub_date, time.max)
```

Result with `pub_date` of `2013-06-05`:

`min_pub_date_time` -> `datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 5, 0, 0)`

`max_pub_date_time` -> `datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 5, 23, 59, 59, 999999)`

Answer (score 23):

Are you sure you don't want to use dates instead of datetimes? If you're always setting the time to midnight, you should consider using a date. If you really want to use datetimes, here's a function to get the same day at midnight:

```
def set_to_midnight(dt):
    midnight = datetime.time(0)
    return datetime.datetime.combine(dt.date(), midnight)
```

Comment: for midnight the other way would I use 86400 instead of 0? This looks very promising

Comment: `midnight = datetime.time(23, 59, 59)`

Comment: Actually, you probably want to use datetime.datetime.max (or min).

Comment: `datetime.combine(dt.date(), datetime.min.time())` worked for me

Answer (score 12):

For tz-aware dates it should be:

```
datetime.combine(dt.date(), datetime.min.time(), dt.tzinfo)
```

Comment: @LidiyaParshina Is it a better way?

Answer (score 1):

`datetime` instance attributes like year, month, day, hour, etc are [read-only](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime), so you just have to create a new `datetime` object and assign it to `end_date`.