# how to get timezone-aware midnight datetime in python?

Tags: python, date, datetime, timezone

I'm working in django, but standard python solution is ok too.

I'm converting a code which uses a naive-datetime to use aware-datetime.

Below is the original code:

```
today = datetime.today()
MyClass.objects.filter(datetimefield__range=(today, today+datetime.timedelta(1)) )
```

How do I convert it to use timezone-aware time?

If the time is jun/3rd/7:20pm locally,
I'd like to get datetime range of `[jun/3rd/00:00am, jun/4th/00:00am]` 
(midnight to midnight which will include `now`)

Comment: What timezone should midnight be *in*? UTC, the server timezone or the timezone of the visitor to your site?

Comment: I'd suggest using `dateutil` library - http://labix.org/python-dateutil

Comment: @JanSpurny: No, that's a great library for parsing and relative date arithmetic. But [Django supports `pytz`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/timezones/) out of the box, so why not stick with that?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is very old, but using django.utils.timezone this is fairly straightforward. 
(nothing concerning timezones ever seems easy to me)

```
# this is could be any datetime.date
my_date = timezone.now().date()
dt_at_local_midnight = timezone.make_aware(
    timezone.datetime.combine(my_date, time.min), 
    timezone.get_current_timezone())
```

and alternative that might be better is listed in the first comment below.

Comment: the first example is incorrect. It may create an unnormalized time (wrong offset) (`.replace()` method may cross a UTC transition boundary). The second example doesn't recognize ambiguous or non-existing times - it silently returns *some* value (it is ok in most cases but you should be aware about it). See [my answer to the duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11236372/4279) that raises an exception in such cases as an alternative.

Comment: That makes sense.. editing the answer, and trying to figure a way to give credit, was looking for the localize method.