# Get the timestamp of the start of a day (local time) without external dependencies

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I wonder if there's any way to get the UNIX timestamp at the beginning of a certain day, i.e the midnight timestamp of each day given its timezone.

Preferably without relying on other pip modules.

Comment: Seconds since epoch or microseconds?

Comment: If you have a `datetime` object, you can just call [`datetime.timestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp).

Comment: ^ This, plus it's pretty easy to create a datetime for midnight local time if you don't have one already.

Comment: Yeah, just use [`datetime.combine()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) with the date you want and a midnight-at-my-timezone time.  You might need pytz to make that work right if you're not using UTC, though.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist seconds is enough.

Comment: In what form do you have "its timezone"? The name of the timezone? That day's UTC offset?

Comment: @Robᵩ an integer, meaning the UTC offset.

Comment: Do you care if the timezone [has changed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY)?  Are you handling daylight savings time?

Comment: Do keep in mind that not all local days start at midnight.  For example, [`2015-10-18` in the south half of Brazil starts at 1:00 AM](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/brazil/sao-paulo?year=2015).  00:00 through 00:59 (and all sub-seconds thereof) do not exist.

Comment: @Kevin I have DST information. And I don't want to take care of timezone changes now.

Comment: @MattJohnson Wow, I see. Thanks for that info.

Comment: related: [python - datetime with timezone to epoch](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12165691/4279)

Comment: related: [How to get system timezone setting and pass it to pytz.timezone?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13218506/4279)

Comment: related: [How to find next day's Unix timestamp for same hour, including DST, in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20276508/4279)

Comment: Not a duplicate (of that question, anyway).  OP is asking about a **UTC offset** rather than a timezone name.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: @Kevin: you don't need the time zone name e.g., you could use `tzlocal.get_localzone()`, to get the local time zone, see the related question that I've linked. Though if OP will [edit] the question and **replace the word "timezone"** with something else then I reopen the question. Unrelated: *your answer encourages wrong results* (UTC offset at midnight may differ from the current UTC offset, moreover 00:00 may not exist in the local time zone on some days, see my answer to the duplicate).

Comment: @JF: OP said in a comment that they have a UTC offset, so that's the question I answered.

Comment: @Kevin: Given that your interpretation (and the corresponding solution) is harmful in most cases (don't equate "timezone" and "utf offset": most timezones may have different utc offset at different times),  OP should demonstrate the intent of the question and therefore OP should  [edit] the question if necessary, not you.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Don't be absurd.  OP specifically said *in the comments* that they have a UTC offset.  Why should it matter which box they put it in?

Comment: @Kevin: a passing remark in comments is enough for innocent statements. On the other hand, brain-dead definitions such as `timezone=utc offset` require explicit consent. To understand the emotion replace ["you can't parse html with regexes" with "time zone is not utc offset" here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian IMHO, it's the OP's responsibility to clarify their issue. OP clearly said that [he has UTC offset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33244911/get-the-timestamp-of-the-start-of-a-day-local-time?noredirect=1#comment54292676_33244911) and [doesn't care about timezone change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33244911/get-the-timestamp-of-the-start-of-a-day-local-time?noredirect=1#comment54295444_33244911). The problem is, OP doesn't realize that given UTC offset only, it cannot determine the correct "named timezone" (even with DST). IMHO, the answer fulfills OP's requirement.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian on the other hand, [it's not OP who wrote "local time" on the title](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33244911/2). So, basically the question is: "get midnight timestamp given a 'timezone' based on its UTC offset (no timezone change, no DST)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you *do not care about daylight savings time* and you *know the UTC offset which was in effect at that time* (as opposed to the UTC offset which is in effect now), you can just do this:

```
import datetime as dt
return dt.datetime(year, month, day, tzinfo=dt.timezone(utc_offset)).timestamp()
```

The hour, minute, and second default to zero, so you can skip them.  The [`timezone`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#timezone-objects) class does not handle daylight savings time, historical changes in timezone definitions (e.g. [British Double Summer Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Summer_Time#Periods_of_deviation)), or any other temporal anomalies (e.g. [there was no December 30, 2011 in Samoa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Samoa)); it is a "dumb" offset.  It is equivalent (in this case) to adding or subtracting the offset directly onto the timestamp and then working in UTC.  You must ensure this is correct for your use case.  If you need better timekeeping, you should install and make use of [pytz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz/).

Comment: The downvoter is welcome to comment on whatever's wrong with this answer.  Since OP is specifically asking about a UTC offset, it's rather difficult for me to give a more "correct" answer to the question as it stands.