# How to get the first datetime of a day?

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x, timezone, pytz

Using pytz and Python 3.4, how to get the first `datetime` of a given day (lets say, 2014-10-19), in a given timezone (lets say `'America/Sao_Paulo'`)?

Comment: Have you a list of `datetime`s? What do you mean with first?

Comment: there are numerous ways to interpret this question, some input and expected output would make it a lot more obvious what you are trying to do.

Comment: By first, I mean the datetime in that day and timezone that is not greater than any other datetime on that day and timezone.

Comment: related: [How do I get the UTC time of “midnight” for a given timezone?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/373370/4279)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `localize()` method to attach the timezone:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz # $ pip install pytz

tz = pytz.timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')    
naive = datetime(2014, 10, 19)
aware = tz.localize(naive, is_dst=None)
```

If you run the code; it generates `NonExistentTimeError`. How to deal with this error depends on the application e.g., to get some valid local time near the midnight:

```
aware = tz.normalize(tz.localize(naive, is_dst=False))
```

Or you could increment the time minute by minute until you'll get a valid local (Sao Paulo) time:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz # $ pip install pytz

tz = pytz.timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')
d = naive = datetime(2014, 10, 19)
while True:
    try:
        aware = tz.localize(d, is_dst=None)
    except pytz.AmbiguousTimeError:
        aware = tz.localize(d, is_dst=False)
        assert tz.localize(d, is_dst=False) > tz.localize(d, is_dst=True)
        break
    except pytz.NonExistentTimeError:
        d += timedelta(minutes=1) # try future time
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Result:

```
>>> aware
datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 19, 1, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Sao_Paulo' BRST-1 day, 22:00:00 DST>
>>> aware.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z')
'2014-10-19 01:00:00 BRST-0200'
```

Note: the first valid time is `01:00` on that day. And the timezone is two hours behind UTC (local = utc - 2).