# How to compare time of Midnight in a given timezone with a UTC timestamp

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to find out whether a given event happened "today" in a given timezone.  My solution is based on other questions posted on S.O, particularly [How do I get the UTC time of "midnight" for a given timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373370/how-do-i-get-the-utc-time-of-midnight-for-a-given-timezone).

The basis of the solution is comparing the UTC time of midnight with the time of the event, but I get an error that the time objects cannot be compared.

The way I get midnight is as follow

```
def midnight_today(timezone):
    tz = pytz.timezone(timezone)
    today = datetime.now(tz).date()
    midnight = tz.localize(datetime.combine(today, time(0, 0)), is_dst=None)
    return midnight.astimezone(pytz.utc)
```

I get an error when I try

```
if time_in > midnight:
   print("Time-in is Today")
```

The error states:

```
  File "/home/shared/Projects/input_validation/validator/echotools.py", line 153, in is_checked_in
    if time_in > midnight:
TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

If I print the times, I can see they look different

```
print(time_in, type(time_in)
2016-12-24 10:15:52.559365 <class 'datetime.datetime'>

print(midnight, type(midnight)
2016-12-23 22:00:00+00:00 <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

So my midnight function returns a time with an offset +00:00, which would be UTC, and 22:00 UTC is indeed midnight at the local time.

So I feel like I am so close to a solution but just need to get over this little hurdle....

Note: I am working in Python 3.5 and do not need to support older version of Python.

Edit:
The marked duplicate question/answer helps ... but I still have a question. (Ref: [How to make an unaware datetime timezone aware in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065164/how-to-make-an-unaware-datetime-timezone-aware-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1))

The answer there proposes that one can either convert the timezone naive time to timezone aware, or vica versa strip the TZ information from the aware timestamp.  I tried both and both methods works.

So I can now either change the midnight_today function to be:

```
def midnight_today(timezone):
    tz = pytz.timezone(timezone)
    today = datetime.now(tz).date()
    midnight = tz.localize(datetime.combine(today, time(0, 0)), is_dst=None)
    return midnight.astimezone(pytz.utc).replace(tzinfo=None)
```

Or else I can change the compare line to be

```
midnight = midnight_today(timezonename)
if timezone(timezonename).localize(time_in) > midnight:
    print("Time-in is Today")
```

My question is what are the gotchas around these - are these special considerations on special days eg when DST is applied?